# WYSIWYG + TinyMCE: Pressing Enter inserts break instead of paragraph

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Does anyone know, how I can manage TinyMCE to insert `<br>` instead of `<p>Paragraphs</p>` when pressing enter?

The best would be if you press enter once, it inserts a normal break. Pressing enter twice it starts a new paragraph.

And yes I know, that Shift+Enter would do it, but my client would like to have the behavior changed.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

Give `shift+enter` a try.

That shortcut tends to be the default in a lot of different text editing apps for break type switching.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... but I know that behavior... but my client doesn't like that ;)

Comment: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE_FAQ#TinyMCE_produce_BR_elements_on_enter.2Freturn_instead_of_P_elements.3F

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the WYSIWYG settings from /admin/config/.  In CKEditor the section **Cleanup and output** has options for *Enter mode* and *Shift+Enter mode* where you set the tag for each action. I'm not 100% about the exact setting for  WYSIWYG, but it should be similar.

Comment: Yes, but that's only for CKEditor and the question was about TinyMCE...